# Does anyone know if you can use PHP for contact form embedded into an html email?

Tags: php, forms, email

I have an html emailer sent out via a program like Mailchimp.  The emailer has an embedded contact form using PHP.  The form works fine when filled in from a browser, but returns a blank email when filled in from the email client.

Any ideas?

Thanks
Jane

Comment: HTML forms in an email = Bad Idea (tm); much of its former glory has faded into oblivion.

Comment: God no. That's asking for trouble.

Comment: @Jack What's `(tm)`? Just curious. :) Yeah, as Jack said, it is a bad idea to use inline forms inside an email, as also many mail providers block `<form>` tag usage inside HTML Emails.

Comment: Very bad idea. E-mail programs are not browsers and should only display  entities limited to text and images. Imagine that browsers differ in functionality and that e-mail clients are much worse, some can´t even read HTML and converts to text. Besides, many of them will view your e-mail as an phishing attempt. See: http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/2435/how-forms-perform-in-html-emai/

Answer (score 2):

No. I'd steer well clear of this. Campaign Monitor has a very good article on this. It goes further than just saying no. Well worth a read but here's the bottom line:

> **The Recommendation:** Given the sporadic support for forms in emails, we
>   recommend linking to a form on a website in an email rather than
>   embedding it therein. This is the safest, most reliable solution to
>   pairing an email message with a form. More people will see it and be
>   able to use it, and as a result participation will increase.

http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/2435/how-forms-perform-in-html-emai/

Comment: Awesome recomendation @SpaceBeers, there is a nice post about that to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18851051/embedded-google-form-in-email