# Embedded Google form in email?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps, google-forms

I'm embedded Google form in email by Google apps script but the form doesn't submit correctly from Outlook and from iPhone. It works from Google Mail client only?

Is there's away to solve this problem of submission from iphone or outlook?

Thanks
Amany

Comment: What problems do you see on Outlook & iPhone. Can you post some screenshots. If this related to Google Apps Script, can you post the code which you're using.

Comment: This is a follow up to [a previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18669532/1677912), code is in that answer.

Answer (score 4):

To use forms embedded in emails, the email client needs to support html forms. Outlook has its own forms, but does not support the html form element ([reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa338201%28v=office.12%29.aspx)). I haven't found a reference for iPhone, but it's likely that it also limits the html support. (I use the gmail client on my phone... it supports forms.)

If you're using the code from [Send form by email and track responses in spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18668828/google-apps-script-send-email-by-script-emails-body-has-link-with-response-ye/18669532#18669532), then you can extend your script to provide a `doGet` function for users that don't have HTML Forms support in their email clients.

The [previous gist](https://gist.github.com/mogsdad/6472790) has been updated with these changes. (Actually, the gist already had the `doGet()` function.)

#### Code.gs

Extend this code by adding a `doGet()` function, which will host the exact same form that you're embedding in the email.

```
/**
 * GET handler to provide alternate online form.
 */
function doGet() {
  // Build survey body
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('emailTemplate');
  template.scriptUrl = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
  template.serialNumber = getGUID();  // Generate serial number for this response
  var app = template.evaluate();
  return app;
}
```

Make the following modification to the `sendSurvey()` function:

```
var plainText = 'Please complete this survey online at: ' + scriptUrl;
html += '<p>Alternatively, you may <A href="' + scriptUrl + '"> complete this survey online.</A>';

// Send email form
GmailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, plainText, {htmlBody:html} );
```

Now, recipients without HTML support in their email client will have a plain text message with an address they can paste into a browser, while HTML clients without `<FORM>` support will have a clickable link to the online form.

Comment: How does the script know whether each user has HTML Forms support in their email client?

Comment: The script cannot know, which is why this solution has you build two alternatives into the email, one for users with plain-text-only, and one for users with HTML but not forms.