# How to send data from form in MailApp.SendEmail

Tags: forms, google-apps-script, gmail

I send email in Google Sheet with function 
`MailApp.SendEmail(email, header, msg, {htmlbody: myHtmlBody});`

In myHtmlBody there are:

```
    <table> ... </table>
    <form>
    <input type="text" />
    <button type="submit">Send back</button>
    </form>
```

What I want: from mail client fill input, click button and get data from this input in my sheet. 
Is there possible?

Comment: Maybe. It depends. Does the email client support forms? You'd still need a webapp to retrieve form submission to google sheet. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18851051/embedded-google-form-in-email#18856329

Comment: @I'-'I Thanks, it looks like what I want. I'll try to do that.